# Parallelism of two or more quantum machines

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-advantage

Suppose I have 2 quantum machines: The first is 2 qubits machine and the second is 4 qubits. Is there a way to parallelize these machines and get a result as if I had 6 quibts machine? Is there a formula to create from several quantum machine another quantum machine that is "stronger" (based on more qubits than each of the separated quantum machines)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you network them together, they can send qubits to each other and thereby act like a combined computer.

For example, in ["Loophole-free Bell inequality violation with superconducting circuits"](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-05885-0/figures/3), two superconducting chips were sending qubits to each other through a waveguide in a cryogenic pipe:

> [image]

This link had a ~20% error rate, so your combined quantum computer would be very bad, but it shows the idea.

Comment: Is there a way to make them running in parallel way and combine their results?

Comment: @Avi Why wouldn't there be. They can both apply operations to the qubits they have, and they can share qubits back and forth.